# Extraneous directories with Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, directory

I created a Cordova project with the following command:

> cordova create test com.test.com test
>
> cd test
>
> cordova platform add ios

When I run these commands, I think I may be getting too many directories, as in the original test directory, I have a www (with index, js, css, etc) and then under platforms/ios/ I also have a www with index, js, css, etc. Is there a reason that there are 2 www directories within the test directory?

Comment: That is expected: there is the base "all platforms" project, and then there is the platform-specific project, which is actually built and packaged into the "native" app. Everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to modify any of the "base" project files? Or do they really do nothing?

Comment: Quite the opposite! The contents of the project-specific folder are generated from the base files. So if you want to actually develop your app, the base files are what need to change.